# How to merge 2 columns of a dataframe in R by making calculations with their respective rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two pairs of columns I want to merge into one. I am a beginner in R, so I do not know, if what I ask is considered simple or not, but I didn't manage to find what I search for on the Internet.

The first pair of columns are "issue_d" (month and year of loan issue) and "earliest_cr_line" (month and year of earliest credit line being opened by the borrower). They are both filled with values that look this way "Dec-2011". I want to create a new joint column to replace them both by subtracting the date of "earliest_cr_line" from "issue_d" for each row, so that my new column "credit_history_length" represents how much time passed since each borrower opened their first credit before issuing their respective loan. How can I do that? By the way, `str(dataframe)` shows that the values in both columns are "chr", which stands for "character", I believe; I was somewhat confused by the whole factor/character problem in several posts I have seen here, so I thought I better provide this piece of information just in case.

Additionaly, I have a second pair of columns "fico_range_high" and "fico_range_low", they both contain "int" values like "600" and "608", I want to replace them with a single column that shows the arithmetic means for each row like "604" for the example above.

How can I create the two desired columns?

Edit: As MrSmithGoesToWashington kindly advised, I put a reproducible sample in here:

```
structure(list(X.1 = 1:5, X = 1:5, id = c(1077501L, 1077430L, 
1077175L, 1076863L, 1075358L), loan_amnt = c(5000L, 2500L, 2400L, 
10000L, 3000L), term = c(" 36 months", " 60 months", " 36 months", 
" 36 months", " 60 months"), grade = c("B", "C", "C", "C", "B"
), sub_grade = c("B2", "C4", "C5", "C1", "B5"), emp_length = c("10+ years", 
"< 1 year", "10+ years", "10+ years", "1 year"), home_ownership = c("RENT", 
"RENT", "RENT", "RENT", "RENT"), annual_inc = c(24000, 30000, 
12252, 49200, 80000), verification_status = c("Verified", "Source Verified", 
"Not Verified", "Source Verified", "Source Verified"), issue_d = c("Dec-2011", 
"Dec-2011", "Dec-2011", "Dec-2011", "Dec-2011"), loan_status = c("Fully Paid", 
"Charged Off", "Fully Paid", "Fully Paid", "Fully Paid"), purpose = c("credit_card", 
"car", "small_business", "other", "other"), dti = c(27.65, 1, 
8.72, 20, 17.94), delinq_2yrs = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), earliest_cr_line = c("Jan-1985", 
"Apr-1999", "Nov-2001", "Feb-1996", "Jan-1996"), fico_range_low = c(735L, 
740L, 735L, 690L, 695L), fico_range_high = c(739L, 744L, 739L, 
694L, 699L), inq_last_6mths = c(1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 0L), mths_since_last_delinq = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 35L, 38L), open_acc = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 15L), pub_rec = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), revol_util = c("83.7%", "9.4%", "98.5%", "21%", 
"53.9%"), total_acc = c(9L, 4L, 10L, 37L, 38L), acc_now_delinq = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), chargeoff_within_12_mths = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), delinq_amnt = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), pub_rec_bankruptcies = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), tax_liens = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you can provide a sample of your data (use dput for exemple), so that somene could work on it and provide you some usefull code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(X.1 = 1:5, X = 1:5, id = c(1077501L, 1077430L, 
1077175L, 1076863L, 1075358L), loan_amnt = c(5000L, 2500L, 2400L, 
10000L, 3000L), term = c(" 36 months", " 60 months", " 36 months", 
" 36 months", " 60 months"), grade = c("B", "C", "C", "C", "B"
), sub_grade = c("B2", "C4", "C5", "C1", "B5"), emp_length = c("10+ years", 
"< 1 year", "10+ years", "10+ years", "1 year"), home_ownership = c("RENT", 
"RENT", "RENT", "RENT", "RENT"), annual_inc = c(24000, 30000, 
12252, 49200, 80000), verification_status = c("Verified", "Source Verified", 
"Not Verified", "Source Verified", "Source Verified"), issue_d = c("Dec-2011", 
"Dec-2011", "Dec-2011", "Dec-2011", "Dec-2011"), loan_status = c("Fully Paid", 
"Charged Off", "Fully Paid", "Fully Paid", "Fully Paid"), purpose = c("credit_card", 
"car", "small_business", "other", "other"), dti = c(27.65, 1, 
8.72, 20, 17.94), delinq_2yrs = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), earliest_cr_line = c("Jan-1985", 
"Apr-1999", "Nov-2001", "Feb-1996", "Jan-1996"), fico_range_low = c(735L, 
740L, 735L, 690L, 695L), fico_range_high = c(739L, 744L, 739L, 
694L, 699L), inq_last_6mths = c(1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 0L), mths_since_last_delinq = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 35L, 38L), open_acc = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 15L), pub_rec = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), revol_util = c("83.7%", "9.4%", "98.5%", "21%", 
"53.9%"), total_acc = c(9L, 4L, 10L, 37L, 38L), acc_now_delinq = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), chargeoff_within_12_mths = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), delinq_amnt = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), pub_rec_bankruptcies = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), tax_liens = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")

df_new <- df %>% mutate(earliest_cr_line = parse_date(paste0("01-", earliest_cr_line), "%d-%b-%Y")) %>% 
                mutate(issue_d          = parse_date(paste0("01-", issue_d), "%d-%b-%Y")) %>% 
                mutate(c_hist           = (issue_d - earliest_cr_line)) %>% 
                mutate(c_hist_months    = round(as.numeric(c_hist)/30, 0)) %>% 
                mutate(fico_mean        = (fico_range_low + fico_range_high)/2) %>% 
                select(earliest_cr_line, issue_d, c_hist, c_hist_months, fico_mean)
df_new
#>   earliest_cr_line    issue_d    c_hist c_hist_months fico_mean
#> 1       1985-01-01 2011-12-01 9830 days           328       737
#> 2       1999-04-01 2011-12-01 4627 days           154       742
#> 3       2001-11-01 2011-12-01 3682 days           123       737
#> 4       1996-02-01 2011-12-01 5782 days           193       692
#> 5       1996-01-01 2011-12-01 5813 days           194       697
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! It totally worked. I will up-vote your answer once I have 15 reputation, right now it just doesn't work, I just hope people won't down-vote me further for my newbie errors in questions haha.

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes too much. For future questions I would suggest to read up on how to best ask a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Part of this is to trim your data to only the relevant stuff. For example, you could have selected only the four relevant columns for your question when you posted.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to make multiple `mutate()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

Naming your input data `dat`, we could use the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  mutate(issue_d_date          = as.Date(paste0(issue_d, "-01"), format = "%b-%Y-%d"),
         earliest_cr_line_date = as.Date(paste0(earliest_cr_line, "-01"), format = "%b-%Y-%d"),
         credit_history_length = issue_d_date - earliest_cr_line_date,
         fico_mean             = apply(across(c(fico_range_high, fico_range_low)), 1, mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Note: since you want to calculate the difference between dates, they also need a day component, so I first appended the first day of each month to your two date variables, and then calculated their difference.

Note 2: it seems your fico range high is always 2 points higher than fico range low. So instead of calculating the mean, a possible alternative could be to simply add 2 to the fico range low.

Here's a snapshot of the relevant variables:

```
   issue_d earliest_cr_line fico_range_high fico_range_low issue_d_date
1 Dec-2011         Jan-1985             739            735   2011-12-01
2 Dec-2011         Apr-1999             744            740   2011-12-01
3 Dec-2011         Nov-2001             739            735   2011-12-01
4 Dec-2011         Feb-1996             694            690   2011-12-01
5 Dec-2011         Jan-1996             699            695   2011-12-01
  earliest_cr_line_date credit_history_length fico_mean
1            1985-01-01             9830 days       737
2            1999-04-01             4627 days       742
3            2001-11-01             3682 days       737
4            1996-02-01             5782 days       692
5            1996-01-01             5813 days       697
```

Comment: For some reason the credit_history_length just showed N/A all across the column, while fico_mean did turn out successful. Thank you for your kind time and effort nevertheless!